# How to find Suffix array and prefix array of a given Array?

Tags: logic, cp

> Given an array such as [4,1,3,2], I need to find the prefix array and
> suffix array of the given array.
>
> For example prefix array of [4,1,3,2] is [4] and suffix array is
> [1,3,2]. and for array [10,20,30,40] prefix array is [] and suffix
> array is [10,20,30,40].
>
> I tried a logic for prefix array which is like this:-
>
> ```
> //given array is [4,1,3,2]
> ArrayList<Integer> prefix=new ArrayList<>();
> int i=0;
>
> while(array[i]>array[i+1]){
> prefix.add(array[i]);
> }
> //after making prefix the rest will be suffix array
> ```
>
> and Rest which remain will be suffix array. This logic is corrected
> for above two arrays but not satisfied many others such as when array
> is [20,69,4,83,23,100,63,50,85,80,53,40,44,1] then prefix is whole
> given array and suffix array is empty array.

I am unable to get the logic for getting prefix and suffix array, any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Also make sure you added all relevant tags.

Comment: where you increase i? in the case array[0]>array[1] you will loop endlessly

Comment: I just forget to add that i++.  Please consider it then tell how can I get prefix array??